# Github CLI - create PR when not in git local repo

Tags: github, command-line-interface, github-cli

Using GitHub gh, how do I create a PR eg

```
gh pr create --repo "owner/repo" --title "PR title" --body "PR body"
```

when not CD'd to the local repo. When I run this command from an arbitrary directory, I get "failed to run git: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" So gh is trying to run git behind the scene.
The owner/repo I think is the remote repo, but I'm looking for a parameter to specify which local repo to use, like git -C "repo".

Answer (score 2):

This is reported by [issue 5465](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5465) and followed by [issue 5075](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5075)

Maybe using `GH_REPO` (as requested in [issue 5061](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5061)) can help (gh 2.5.1+), but only with `gh api`.

If not, doing a manual `cd` first seems the only option.

Comment: Closer but not quite there. This works perfectly fine for "remote only" commands like `GH_REPO=owner/repo gh pr list` but to create a PR you need to specify what branch you are on. So the missing bit is the equivalent of `cd localGitRepo; git checkout branchName`. Thanks for advice

Comment: @wavefront I suspect https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5465#issuecomment-1143781469 shows a similar issue indeed.